# Leakage prevention in Valgrind

Tags: c++, visual-c++, valgrind

```
    void  update(int s) {
 68     double *ungfi = new double[arraysisasazei];
 69     double *vnsasai = new double[arraysizasaei];
 70     deriv(dvsasi,vnsasai );
 71     deriv(dusaasi,ungfi );
```

for the above code below are my errors arising and thank you to kerrek SB for the reply

```
 ==745== 800,000 bytes in 1,000 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you're forgetting to delete the arrays before returning from the function. Since it's difficult to get that right (in case an exception is thrown), use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to manage the arrays:

```
std::vector<double> uni(arraysizei);
std::vector<double> vni(arraysizei);
```

and access the raw arrays as `uni.data()` and `vni.data()` if you need to.

If you really feel like juggling pointers yourself for some reason, remember to delete with `delete []` to match the `new []`. Remember to do this on every possible return path; even then, you'll have a leak if anything throws an exception.

Comment: if i use delete [] uni; I am getting a error as expected unqualified-id before ‘delete’

Comment: @user2830047: Did you add the delete *inside* the function, before it returns? I get that error if I (erroneously) put it *outside* the function.

Comment: @user2830047: And if you really, really want to use `delete` yourself, despite my advice, make sure you cover every possible return path. Even then, you're likely to have a leak if anything throws an exception. It's much, much better to use RAII to manage dynamic resources.